# I am trying to make a matrix of ones and zeros but I get only ones

Tags: python, list

I want to transform a list of the form [['name', label], ..., ['nameN', labelN]] of size n into an nxn matrix with zeros except for places where for certain positions the labels are the same.  Basically i want to ultimately make a .csv file that I can put into Gephi and make a network. I tried a "double for loop with an if statement" but contrary to my expectation I obtained all ones.

Here's my code:

```
list
[['ASV33', 0],
['ASV58', 1],
['ASV61', 0],
['ASV62', 2],
['ASV73', 3],
['ASV75', 4],
['ASV86', 5],
['ASV91', 6],
['ASV99', 7],
['ASV100', 8],
['ASV109', 7],
['ASV110', 9]]
```

...and so on...
Here I make a nxn array of zeros

```py
    rows, cols = (n, n)
    arr = [[0]*cols]*rows
```

and here s the code where I want to make the cells one if the labels for the columns and the labels for the rows are the same.

```
for g in range(0,len(list)):
    for h in range(g,len(list)):
        if (list[g][1] == list[h][1]):
            arr[g][h] = 1
            print(g,h)
        else:
            arr[g][h] = 0
```

Every time I call `arr[k][l]` I get a one even if `list[k][1] != list[l][1]`

Comment: Note: `arr` is a list, not an array

Comment: What is `n`? Is it `len(arr)`?